# Using linregress | ImportError

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a regression on a dataframe `dfMyRoll` with a `head()` that look like:

```
dfMyRoll = pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, usecols=[0,31],parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['date', 'SCORE'])
dfMyRoll['SCORE_LAG'] = dfMyRoll['SCORE'].shift(1)

date           SCORE  SCORE_LAG                      
2007-10-29 -2.546807        NaN
2007-10-30 -2.513166  -2.546807
2007-10-31 -3.493106  -2.513166
2007-11-01 -3.008866  -3.493106
2007-11-02 -6.813640  -3.008866
```

I am trying to is scipy `linregress` by using the following:

```
slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress( dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE'],dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE_LAG'])
```

I import scipy in the following way:

```
import scipy
from scipy.stats import linregress
```

but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have checked to see if I have imported scipy:

```
scipy.__version__
Out[21]: '0.17.0

scipy.version.full_version
Out[22]: '0.17.0'
```

and that seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your version of `scipy` might be old. Try using the following in your command prompt if you are using conda:

```
conda update scipy
```

The latest version of `scipy` is 0.19.0